# Wordpress $wpdb prepare on external sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, wordpress

I'm trying to ensure my Wordpress code is all safe from SQL injections and trying to use $wpdb->prepare() to ensure this. However, it doesn't seem to be function correctly.

The code I am practicing with pulls data from a different SQL database on the same server (i.e not from the wordpesss database). The code I use is:

```
$mydb = new $wpdb('databese_username','password','datbasename', 'host');
$id = 2;
$users = $mydb->get_results( $mydb->prepare("SELECT table.column
                             FROM table.column
                             INNER JOIN table ON table.column = table.column
                             WHERE table.column = %d",$id));
```

This is fine for getting the data but it is not clear whether the prepare() is working and would stop sql injection if used in other ways. My concern is that I can easily change $id to a string (i.e $id = "2"; ) and the code still gets my data. Shouldn't prepare stop this from working?

How do I properly use the prepare when using an external database? Is it $mydb->prepare() or should it be $wpdb->prepare() or something else?

Thanks

Comment: prepared statements still let you send invalid data, it just wont treat that data as possible sql commands.

Comment: Thanks pala, but what does this actually mean? Do I not need to worry that my code returns data regardless of whether I send use an integer or a string?

Comment: then it will be a string, and instead of being `table.column = 5` it would be `table.column = 'some string'`, and no matter what value they put for the string, it will still be fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to already connected with wordpress database. so you have not need to connection to data base.. you can use global $wpdb;

```
global $wpdb; 
$id = 2;
$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT table.column
                             FROM table.column
                             INNER JOIN table ON table.column = table.column
                             WHERE table.column = %d",$id);
```